# How to use ReceivedDateTime filter using Graph client in C#

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

How to use email message ReceivedDateTime filter using Graph client in C#

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `Filter` method.

Example how to filter messages in March 2022:

API call:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=receivedDateTime ge 2022-03-01 and receivedDateTime lt 2022-04-01
```

C#:

```
var filter = "receivedDateTime ge 2022-03-01 and receivedDateTime lt 2022-04-01";
var messages = await graphClient.Me.Messages
    .Request()
    .Filter(filter)
    .GetAsync();
```

Filter by exact date time:

```
var dateTimeStr = new DateTime(2022,3,7,09,27,50).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
var filter = $"receivedDateTime eq {dateTimeStr}";
var messages = await graphClient.Me.Messages
    .Request()
    .Filter(filter)
    .GetAsync();
```

Filter messages older than 30 days

```
var days = 30;
var dateTimeStr = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(days)).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
var filter = $"receivedDateTime lt {dateTimeStr}";
var messages = await graphClient.Me.Messages
    .Request()
    .Filter(filter)
    .GetAsync();
```

Resources:

[filter query operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#examples-using-the-filter-query-operator)

Comment: Thanks for reply! In filter I need receiveddatetime eq to specific date time 
Request().Filter($"ReceivedDateTime ge eq '{3/7/2022 9:27:50 AM +00:00}'").GetAsync();
This call is not working with Graphclient in C#

Comment: @SCTest I've updated my answer with an example for filtering by exact date time.

Comment: How to get only messages older than say 30 days using GraphServiceClient?

Comment: @Holm76 Check updated answer. I've added an example how to filter messages older than x days

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick answer. By the way what does 'lt' and 'ge' stand for?

Comment: @Holm76 Less than (lt)
Greater than (gt)
Less than or equal to (le)
Greater than or equal to (ge)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?view=graph-rest-1.0#operators-and-functions-supported-in-filter-expressions